# Lua: Piece of code to a specific circumstance

Tags: lua

I'm making a (poor) cryptography script in Lua and for this, I need to make a *loop* that will return a value for each number in a string, for example:

```
Input: 15, 18, 1, 20, 15, 18, 15, 5, 21, 1, 18, 15, 21, 16, 1, 4, 15, 18, 5, 9, 4, 5, 18, 15, 13, 1
```

And I want it to return each of these digits to a function which will do a certain math with them, then return the correspondent letter for each of the resulting numbers (15 will become 'o', 18 will become 'r' and so on)

Explaining in detail, I need the a piece of code to insert into a function that will:

1. Return each of the numbers in a string to a function.
2. After this, the function needs to convert the numbers into letters (as previously said).
3. Then a new function needs to insert the resulting letters in a new string.

Here's a brief example of how it needs to behave.

```
Input: 8, 5, 12, 12, 15
Result: 26, 7, 15, 15, 12 (These numbers aren't constant because of a hidden math made inside the function.)

Input: 26, 7, 15, 15, 12
Result: z, g, o, o, l

Input: z, g, o, o, l
Result: "zgool"
```

I think the source code of this project isn't necessary for this occasion, I'll just implement this code into the functions on the script. Please, someone (who understands what I meant) can help me?

Comment: What help do you want, you say "source code isn't necessary".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant that the script's source code isn't necessary.

Comment: So you just want someone to write code for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
local function my_poor_cryptography(s)
   local codes = {}
   -- string to numbers
   for c in s:gmatch"%a" do
      table.insert(codes, c:byte() - (c:find"%l" and 96 or 64))
   end
   -- math here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)
   for j = 1, #codes do
      codes[j] = (codes[j] + 12) % 26 + 1
   end
   -- numbers to string
   s = s:gsub("%a", 
      function(c) 
         return c.char(table.remove(codes, 1) + (c:find"%l" and 96 or 64)) 
      end)
   return s
end
```

Usage:

```
local str = "Hello, World!"
str = my_poor_cryptography(str)
print(str)     --> Uryyb, Jbeyq!
str = my_poor_cryptography(str)
print(str)     --> Hello, World!
```

Comment: @zaph - It depends... :-)

Comment: I am thinking AES GCM, just the Galois field multiplication portion. 

Comment: Oh my god that's not what I meant.
I meant I need a piece of code that for each number in the string, it will call another function that'll convert those numbers and then write the resulting numbers in another string.

Comment: @iiHarvx - You can call your function inside the loop in the `-- math here` section.

Comment: I knew he can do it :)